# How to test ChromeOS enterprise features during development?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I am working on a Chrome extension running on Chrome OS.
The extension needs the `enterprise.hardwarePlatform` permission to be able to get hardware information about the device.
The question is: How can I test my extension?

After installing the extension manually, the API to get the hardware information will not work as it needs the extension to be forced-installed by the enterprise policy.
But how to force-install the extension if it is not published in the Chrome Web Store?
Google Workspace seems to allow to refer only to published extensions in the enterprise policy. But obviously I do not want to publish the extension under development. Also I didn't find a "Web Store for development" where I could upload the extension and then refer to it from the policy.
So how to do this?

I found this question:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/107510644/how-do-i-develop-a-chrome-extension-with-enterprise-permissions?hl=en-gb
However, did not find the answer in any of the provided links. All information seem to point to publishing on Chrome Web Store first. But then would it be impossible to manually test a feature like this before publishing?

Thank you for your answers in advance.